# Solved Programming Challenges Dataset

Tags: data-request, api, nlp, programming

I'm looking for a dataset of solved programming challenges, like the ones on http://codeeval.com. The dataset should have the natural language description of the problem and N solutions for each problem, possibly in different programming languages.

An API for extracting this kind of data from some programming challenges site would fit too.

Comment: Wish this had more traction and answers... Tried the google data set search and got no results as well

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to piece it together, but Project Euler has many solutions to the same problems hosted on github

https://github.com/topics/project-euler

You can get the text of the problems with the URL

https://projecteuler.net/problem=719

and also some machine readable info from the questions: https://projecteuler.chat/viewtopic.php?t=3003